# Setup page title in the site tree always on English dependently which language is selected for editing

Tags: sxa

I would like to setup **page title** in the site tree in English independently which language is selected for editing and also no `display name` for item name.

I mean this section:

```
Display name - Is shown in the content editor
```

Comment: Do you want to say that if you have selected any other language version like french for editing then the page title component should show the English version ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to go to that page's template and check for the field, that value you want to make the same for all the language versions.

And then you need to check the `Shared` check box that will allow you to use the same field value for all the language versions.

[image]

Now if you will create the item in any language then it will come with the default value that you have provided in your default language version. i.e. English.

And if a content user will forcefully edit it in a particular language version then it will be changed, otherwise not.

Comment: This looks like the only way to achieve what @eratosten123 is looking for but it has a lot of risks attached. This will affect how Title displays on site (only English). Also it will affect  search capability, Browser Title (default) etc. Just beware.

Answer (score -1):

You can make `__Display name` field to `Shared` of item path `/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Appearance`

[image]

At any point of time, it will have one value across the all available language and the same value will be visible in you Sitecore content tree.

Comment: It is not recommended to update the system template fields.

Comment: Agreed Mahendra!!! What is the way to achieve this... Might have to do lots of customization.

Comment: Yes, I need to make display name for other languages to display only English version always.